# Is possible to run headless Selenium under WSL (Linux under Windows)?

Tags: linux, selenium

My question is if it is even possible to run headless browser (no matter if under WSL or Linux Server without XWindows)?

I have program in Python for Selenium and I downloaded and added path to geckodriver to PATH. But I am ending with this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
  File "/home/pavel/projekty/env38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/pavel/projekty/env38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/pavel/projekty/env38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/pavel/projekty/env38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pavel/projekty/env38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I guess it is impossible but I wonder if there is any solution.

Comment: I have run my selenium script with headless browser in Linux without GUI. Maybe you can check your geckodriver version (Windows or Linux).

Comment: Thanks. I am using this version: 0.27.0